# Нахождение вложенного пустого JSON-массива с помощью операторов класса jsonb_ops индекса GIN

Tags: postgresql, индексы, jsonb

Есть таблица. В ней поле `data` типа `jsonb`. Записи вида `{"a":[]}` или `{"a":["foo"]}`. На поле  `data` есть GIN-индекс с классом операторов `jsonb_ops`, соответственно наиболее эффективны операторы `?`, `?&`, `?|`, и `@>`.

Вопрос: Как с помощью этих операторов найти записи, в которых в ключе `"a"` пустой массив? Лучше всего только с помощью `@>`, чтобы использовать класс `jsonb_path_ops`.

Если это невозможно, поясните, почему.

Пробовал:

```sql
-- Верно, TRUE.
postgres=# SELECT CAST('{"a":[]}' AS jsonb) @> '{"a":[]}';
 ?column?
----------
 t
(1 row)

-- Неверно, должно быть не TRUE.
postgres=# SELECT CAST('{"a":[1]}' AS jsonb) @> '{"a":[]}';
 ?column?
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL 12 или новее:

```
postgres=# select CAST('{"a":[1]}' AS jsonb) @@ '$.a.size() == 0';
 ?column? 
----------
 f
(1 row)

postgres=# select CAST('{"a":[]}' AS jsonb) @@ '$.a.size() == 0';
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

Для этого оператора реализована поддержка GIN индексов opclass'ами `jsonb_path_ops` и `jsonb_ops`. Впрочем, не спрашивайте насколько поддержка индексов для jsonpath хорошая для этого случая. В моём тесте поиска одной строки с пустым массивом из 100 тысяч seqscan быстрее.

Зато это является стандартным синтаксисом выражений поиска по JSON.

---

Для версий более старых - JSON массивы в принципе неудобны в обработке. Не хватает ни операторов ни даже встроенных функций. Например даже:

```
postgres=# select jsonb '[1]' ? '1';
 ?column? 
----------
 f

postgres=# select jsonb '["1"]' ? '1';
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

Как правило приходится разворачивать в набор строк через `jsonb_array_elements` и обрабатывать в подзапросе. О поддержке индексов речь можно заводить только в контексте пользовательской или встроенной `immutable` функции и построении индекса с ней.

Например, если вам надо найти ограниченное число строку с пустым массивом, можно создать:

```
create index on tablename (id /*или другое поле полезное для поиска*/) where jsonb_array_length(js->'a') = 0;
```

Либо если нужно искать длины массива не только 0:

```
create index on tablename (jsonb_array_length(js->'a'));
```

Comment: Ясно, спасибо за ответ. Можете уточнить, будет ли работать запрос `$.a.size() == 0`, если атрибута `a` нету вообще, и если нет, как можно выбрать все записи, где `a` нет, или `a` — пустой массив?

Comment: если атрибута нет - то даст NULL, что where отфильтрует. Можно явно дописать `'!exists($.a) || $.a.size() == 0'`